# Xcode15のユーザーインターフェイスで電卓ボタンを格子状に配置したいです！

Tags: swift, xcode

Xcode15をViewcontrollerを使用して電卓ボタンを格子状に配置する為にStackViewを作成して各ボタンを追加したのですが、ボタンサイズが自動的に縮小されてしまい横向きに均等に配置することができない状況です。

Distributionを「Fill Equality」に指定することで均等配置が出来ると学習サイトで見つけたので試してみましたが、、画像のようにボタンが縮小されてしまいました。
（※constrainは設定していない状態です）
（※画像には完成形と現状を添付しました）

ボタンを綺麗に配置するためには他に設定が必要でしょうか。
良い解決法を教えて頂けると幸いです！[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 関連するソースコードも質問に含まれていると回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

ボタンのサイズについて、Horizontal Stack View等のオブジェクトのサイズをアスペクト比固定にすることで、任意の縦横比を維持することが出来るのではないでしょうか？

こちらのサイト等が参考になると思います！

[実践で学ぶAutoLayoutの使い方～SwiftからはじめるiOSアプリ開発:その6](https://type.jp/et/feature/3137/)